# Given a pixel coordinates, how can I extract all his neighbors?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I want to build a 3x3 block for a given matrix point with that point in the center of the block. This is my code :

```
function frmBlock = fetchNeighbors(frame, row, column)
%Create a 3x3 matrix contains the neighbors of the point(x, y)
%[n, m] = size(frame);
frmBlock = zeros(3, 3);
x = floor(row);
y = floor(column);
    frmBlock(1) = frame(x-1, y-1);
    frmBlock(2) = frame(x, y-1);
    frmBlock(3) = frame(x+1, y+1);
    frmBlock(4) = frame(x-1, y);
    frmBlock(5) = frame(x, y);
    frmBlock(6) = frame(x+1, y);
    frmBlock(7) = frame(x-1, y+1);
    frmBlock(8) = frame(x, y+1);
    frmBlock(9) = frame(x+1, y-1);
end
```

As you can see, I create a 3x3 matrix initialized by 0. What I want to do is to fill that matrix with all the neighbors of the coordinate in input(row, column). If I can't get the neighbors for some reason I do nothing (i.e let that position in the 3x3 block as 0).

When I run this code I got an error saying:

`Error using fetchNeighbors (line 12) Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Can someone help ?

Comment: If you have colour image in RGB format, you need `frmBlock=nan(3,3,3)`. Third dimension is RBG vector. `frmBlock(1,1,:)=frame(x-1,y-1,:)` shall do the trick for one pixel.

Comment: No I don't have a colour image.

Comment: I update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that the error is due to the fact that you are taking `row` and `column` to be on the boundaries of the matrix `frame`, and then when you try to access the element just right or left or below or above (depends on which boundary you are on), you are out of bounds and this raises the error. For example, if `row` equals `1`, this means that at some point you are trying to access `frame(0,column)`, which is illegal.

You can fix this by adding a check (using an `if` statement) before any access to the matrix, to make sure you are in bounds. I add here an alternative approach:

```
function frmBlock = fetchNeighbors(frame, row, column)
% Create a 3x3 matrix that contains the neighbors of the point (row,column)
    [n,m] = size(frame);
    neighbors_x = max(row-1,1):min(row+1,n);
    neighbors_y = max(column-1,1):min(column+1,m);
    frmBlock = zeros(3,3);
    frmBlock(neighbors_x-row+2,neighbors_y-column+2) = frame(neighbors_x,neighbors_y);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked, just one last thing if I may, the input(row, column) are not integer, they are real, so a used the `round()` function on them but I got this error :  `Invalid indexing operation`

Comment: Accessing a matrix at a non-integer index in not valid. If you make sure to round the integer, you should not get that error. If you do, I suggest you recheck your code, and if the problem persists open a new StackOverflow question to target that issue. You can add the link to the question here in the comments.

Comment: Thanks again @Lior.